# send a .apk file from REST web service to client?

Tags: java, android, rest

I want send my android .apk file to my client(browser) from java restful web service.I try to use bellow code. But it produce a file named "MyPath" without any file extension (require .apk).Thanks in advance

```
@Path("MyPath")
public class MyPathResource {
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of MyPathResource
     */
    public MyPathResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    public File getFile() {
        // return my file
        return new File("E:\\CommandLineAndroidProjet1\\bin\\FirstCommandLineApp-release.apk");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an explicit `javax.ws.core.Response`:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(entity)
                .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
                .build();
```

while `entity` is your file as byte array and `fileName` is the file name with `.apk` suffix.